# change sequence of datagridview columns window C#

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am creating window c# desktop application
I have three columns in my datagridview

column1  is  DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn
and column 2 and column 3 is bounded through datatable.
Now i want that sequence of column should come as follows:

Column2  Column3  and Column1
but it is coming like as follows :

Column1 Column2  Column3

I want that DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn should come as last column of datagridview

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change display order of columns in design time.

In design window, open the designing window of DataGridView, and the columns will be listed. You can re-arrange column by clicking up/down button on designing window.

You can change display order programmatically by adding order of it, for e.g :

```
DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn col3 = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn ();
//...
DataGridViewTextBoxColumn col1 = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn ();
//...
DataGridViewTextBoxColumn col2 = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn ();
//...

datagridview.columns.add(col3);
datagridview.columns.add(col1);
datagridview.columns.add(col2);
```

HTH.

Answer (score 3):

You could do

```
datagridview.columns("Column2").displayIndex = 0
datagridview.columns("Column3").displayIndex = 1
datagridview.columns("Column1").displayIndex = 2
```

after the binding occurs (after the data has shown on the datagridview)

Answer (score 0):

See this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumncollection.addrange.aspx). For example, the following code will add two columns from database and one `DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn` as `Column1` in the middle of the two database columns. So the code will look like this

```
this.dataGridView1.Columns.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumn[] {
        this.midDataGridViewTextBoxColumn,
        this.Column1,
        this.nameDataGridViewTextBoxColumn
        });
```